# PowerShell: Почему не работает msg на несколько компов в условии?

Tags: powershell

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема?

Написал простейший скрипт на `PS`, который пингует сайт, в случае неполучения ответа перезагружает сетевой адаптер и отправляет на компы из списка с помощью `msg` сообщение. Но, почему-то отдельная функция, рассылающая сообщения, при вызове нормально работает, а при вызове в условии выдает ошибку:

```
Ошибка 1722 при получении имени сеанса
C:\Users\username\Desktop\PS\CheckInternet.ps1:22 знак:6
+      msg $Session /Server:$Recepient $Message
+      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (Ошибка 1722 при получении имени сеанса:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

Сам код:

```
$Site = "ya.ru"
$ListRecepients = Get-Content "C:\Scripts\recepients.txt"
$Session = "*"
$Message = "Доступ в интернет отсутствует. Начинаю перезагрузку сетевого адаптера"

function PingSite {
if ((Test-Connection -CN $Site -Count 1 -BufferSize 16 -Quiet) -match 'True') 
    {
     write-host -ForegroundColor green Done 
     } 
else 
    {
     write-host -ForegroundColor red Undone         
     WTF
     Restart-NetAdapter -Name "Ethernet" 
     }
}

function WTF {
ForEach ($Recepient in $ListRecepients) 
    {
     msg $Session /Server:$Recepient $Message
     }
}
```

Причем, погуглив, даже поправил в реестре ключик `AllowRPC`, однако результат тот же.

Comment: попробуйте `msg $Session /Server:$Recepient $Message 2> $null`

Comment: это лишь уберет сообщение об ошибке, но не решит главной проблемы, мессейдж на остальные машины не улетает. Проверил, так и есть :(

Comment: отправьте из консоли(без скрипта, одной командой). точно не доходят? вы из консоли получаете такую же ошибку всегда?

Comment: Одной командой все улетает, и если просто вызвать функцию WTF, то все гут, а вот если в условии, то все - ошибка

Comment: логиркйте  этот момент. я бумаю неправильные параметры подставляются для msg

Comment: Перевёл текст ошибки через 2cyr. Судя по ошибке, проблема в имени сеанса. Уберите переменную `$Session` и попробуйте вызывать так: `& msg * /Server:$Recepient "$Message"` (амперсанд в начале для верности).